# PHP and Redirect with apache2.conf

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have an internal domain like

live.domain.com

which I defined in sites-available like so

```
ServerName live.domain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /data/www/html/mydomainnamenodots 

        <Directory /data/www/html/mydomainnamenodots>
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

and the accordingly same for SSL conf.

I do have a folder **/api** which is in there like
/data/www/html/mydomainnamenodots/api

What I want is to catch all calls to 
`live.domain.com/api/*`

and redirect them to something like 
`live.domain.com/api/index.php?url=*`

So a real example would be

`live.domain.com/api/statistics/getFTE/123/456`

and I'd like that to be

`live.domain.com/api/index.php?url=/statistics/getFTE/123/456`

That would result in a $_REQUEST in index.php like so

`array(1) {["url"]=>string(33) "/statistics/getFTE/123/456"}`

mod_rewrite is enabled and loaded. Simple tests with file to file redirects work.

My rewrite rule which does not work as it does not redirect is

```
<Directory "/data/www/html/mydomainnamenodots/api">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*?mydomainnamenodots\/api(.*)$ /mydomainnamenodots/api/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

Any ideas why that does not work?
Am I missing the RewriteBase or something?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: `RewriteRule` matches against the path component of the requested URL. Your requested URL does not contain `mydomainnamenodots` in the path.

Comment: Ok - I changed it to ```RewriteRule ^.*?api(.*)$ /api/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]``` getting ```Not Found

The requested URL /api/statistics/getFTE/9936514/131331 was not found on this server.```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `.*?` at the beginning, if what you want to match starts with `/api/`? // Try and take this out of the `Directory` container you currently have this in, not sure if that matches to begin with.

Comment: Uncommenting <Directory> parts results in the same error. But may be I do not get your point correctly. Would you mind to change my rewriterule to reflect your suggestions?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the subdomain already points to a subfolder, it has to be the the according subfolder below that one in the directory definition. In addition I changed the regexp as well.

Here is what worked for me:

```
<Directory />
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^.*\/api(\/.*)$ /api/index.php?url=\/$1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```